# How to overwrite 'read more" text for artmag theme

Tags: functions

I use Artmag Theme but forgot to ask how to update "read more" text. Anyway I hope I'm able to do it by myself but can not find any possibilities in css editor ? There are *Excerpt Read More* in functions.php and it looks like this:

```
function artmag_fm_more_link() {
    return '<div class="full-width margint20"><div class="read-more button clearfix"><a href="' .
        get_permalink() . '">'. __("Read More","artmag") .' <span class="arrow-right">'.
        (is_rtl() ? "&#8592;" : "&#8594") .'</span></a></div></div>';
}

add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'artmag_fm_more_link', 10, 2);

function artmag_pagination_query($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query()) {
        if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
        elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
        else { $paged = 1; }
        $query->set('paged',$paged);
        }
    }

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'artmag_pagination_query' );
```

I have no idea how to replace 'read more' links with my custom text ... Anyone can help ?

Comment: Please contact the theme author. A standard WordPress excerpt filter won't help in your case - this theme has custom functions so you'll need to have their help to make adjustments.

Comment: @Kadya if you just want it to say something other than `Read More`, just changing that text in `__("Read More","artmag")` will probably do the trick =]

Answer (score 1):

To change the text of the "Read More" link, you simply need to hook into `the_content_more_link` at a higher priority.

You can add this to your child theme functions.php file and it should replace the "Read More" text with "Your Preferred Link Text".

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'wpse_260911_more_link', 11, 2 );
function wpse_260911_more_link( $more_link, $not_used ) {
  return str_ireplace( 'Read More', 'Your Preferred Link Text', $more_link );
}
```

If you aren't using a child theme ( you really should be ), then you can create a simple plugin that does the same thing. Take the code above, add the following above it, create a ZIP file that contains only this file, upload it, and activate from the dashboard.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Filter Artmag Read More link
 */
```